# Sort text alpha numerically in excel

Tags: excel

I have part number data in a spreadsheet that has been converted to text data (not numeric as there are letters) that I need to sort alpha numerically.  I have read enough that this appears to be almost impossible due to nulls (I have none of these) dashes (I have tons of these).  As you will see below, there are multiple letters and numbers in different locations in the field.

```
MS16624-2066
RWR80S
02-6009-23
23032-1910
31708-1370
11SM1-T
111SM1-5
```

The final result required is:

```
MS16624-2066
RWR80S
02-6009-23
11SM1-T 
111SM1-5
23032-1910
31708-1370
```

I have tried as much as I could by looking at the sorts in this forum, but have had no luck. Can anyone suggest a working approach?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Why can't you just sort this list? It will be 02-6009-23 at the bottom and RWR80S at the top. Is that not what you want?

Comment: What does this have to do with [tag:ms-access]?

Comment: Hi Gord,  I was looking for answers in any format.

Comment: Hi JNevill.  I need the final output to be true alpha numeric, not excel or access sort of format.  I will edit the question for the results.

Comment: Can you clarify your definition of 'true alpha numeric' ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming part numbers are in ColumnA starting in A1, in B1:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","")
```

Copy down to suit then Copy ColumnB and Paste Special, Values over the top.

Apply Text to Columns, Fixed width to ColumnB and choose character by character (positions 1 to 11 for your example).

Then sort A:M on ColumnC descending and move the rows with `C` numbers below the `C` letters.

You may then choose to delete ColumnsB:M.